# How to generate a multi target regression dataset for different target ranges (or patterns)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

We can generate a multi-target regression dataset using the `make_regression()` function of the `sklearn`. Here, the number of targets is `2

```
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=5000, n_features=10, n_informative=7, n_targets=2, random_state=1, noise=5)
```

Now, I want to make a multi-target dataset where the ranges (or patterns) of the `target` variables will be different. So that different ML models can fit and predict well for different targets.

Say, I have 2 targets in a dataset. Target 1 might fit and predict very well by `Linear`, `Lasso`, or `Ridge` while target 2 will fit and predict well by `RF`, `SVR` or `Knn`.

Any idea how can I make this type of dataset?

Answer (score 0):

According to the document (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_regression.html), this function generates data by a linear regression model. This means data generated by this function should fit well by linear methods.  Perhaps lasso would work better if the number of informative features is much smaller than the number of all features because lasso tends to create sparse models.

To generate data that does not fit well with linear models, but good with non-linear models such as RF, SVR, KNN, you will need to add non-linearity to the data.  As an example approach, transforming `y` by some non-linear function such as `sin(y)` may work (I did not try though).

Comment: Thanks, I applied `sin()` on target-2. For target-1 every model is getting good `r2` such as linreg `0.99` while RF `0.98`. But for target-2 every model is getting negative r2. Any idea?

Comment: Negative r2 means the model is worse than the constant prediction with the average.  This often happens when the features are useless.  In this case, however you have at least some useful features.  So if there is no bug in the procedure, the best guess I could make is that the model tuning did not go well.

Comment: I didn't tune any ML model. I am using the default one!